# reactjs firebase 'push' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have defined the firebase in my reactjs app as follow (requires are correct with firebase v2)

```
var App = React.createClass({
  mixins: [ReactFire],
  componentWillMount: function () {this.bindAsObject(new Firebase(rootURL + 'items/'), 'items')},
  render: function () {return <Header itemStore={this.firebaseRefs.items}/>}});
```

and I call the props in header class as fallow:

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {text: ''}
    },
    render: function () {return <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>},
    handleClick: function () {this.props.itemStore.push({
            text:this.state.text,
            done:false
        });
        this.setState({text:''});
    }
});
```

but I face error as  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

Comment: Seems to be you have a typo in `items`. Just check it:   `componentWillMount: function () {this.bindAsObject(new Firebase(rootURL + 'items/'), 'itmes')}`, //itmes should be items I believe

Comment: @cubbuk thanks, actually the mistype was here during copy paste, not in project :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your class the following:

```
    propTypes: {
        itemStore: ReactPropTypes.object
    }
```

Your class will end up like this:

```
var ReactPropTypes = React.PropTypes;

module.exports = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        itemStore: ReactPropTypes.object
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {text: ''}
    },

    render: function () {return <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>},
    handleClick: function () {this.props.itemStore.push({
            text:this.state.text,
            done:false
        });
        this.setState({text:''});
    }
});
```

Comment: I have already created an element from my main class and render it with reactDOM, and do not need to dispatch props service. BTW I tried your solution and did not work, thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, it had to be the following: propTypes: {
        itemStore: ReactPropTypes.object
    }

Comment: `propTypes: { 
    itemStore: ReactPropTypes.object 
}`

Comment: I applied the change, but the same issue, it seems the instance of firebase does not have 'push' at all.

Comment: I guess the problem is architecture. You should declare a function in store that makes the push to the store variable where you save the items. Then yous should call that function and put the object in that call as parameter.

Comment: Take a look at this excellent tutorial https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/todo-list.html#creating-stores ;)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that this.props.itemStore is undefined.  The undefined type doesn't have the 'push' method available.

What does `this.props.itemStore` look like when you console.log it inside the click handler and then click?  If it's undefined, what does `this.props` look like?